# Jquery repetitive class sector use to add/remove classes on multiple items

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

So what i am trying to achieve is to change the class of an image, which i have done with the following code.

The `show_hidden` class makes the image invisible and `width:0` and `height:0`

Each button shows and adds a hidden class to the image element

```
$(".button_1").click(function() {
    $(".show_2, .show_3").addClass("show_hidden");
    $(".show_1").removeClass("show_hidden");
});

$(".button_2").click(function() {
    $(".show_1, .show_3").addClass("show_hidden");
    $(".show_2").removeClass("show_hidden");
});

$(".button_3").click(function() {
    $(".show_1, .show_2").addClass("show_hidden");
    $(".show_3").removeClass("show_hidden");
});
```

This effects a wordpress loop that creates instances of an item dependent on how many posts there are. (* i have left out the images specifics in the code below)

```
<?php  if (is_page)()({
foreach ($posts as post): 
setup_postdata($post);//setup variables inside the loop  
?>
<div class="container_left">
    <div class="show_1"><img></div>
    <div class="show_2 show_hidden"><img></div>
    <div class="show_3 show_hidden"><img></div>
</div>
<div class="container_right">
    <div class="inner_right">
        <div class="button_1"></div>
        <div class="button_2"></div>
        <div class="button_3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

So what currently happens is the code creates the items for however many posts there are and the image changes as it should, however it effects every post created. Meaning that when `button_1` from `post_1` is pressed it changes the images for posts 1-3, instead of just post 1.

I'm a bit out of my depth with the syntax of the problem, I believe the issue is inheritance based and that a `$this` function would sort it out. However there seems to be an issue with the buttons being nested in a 2nd layer (*they need to be as they are found in a separate section on the page).

The closest solution I have found to my issue can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/PBbmf/1/

However again I think because the buttons are nested in another layer it causes an issue with the `$this` function.

Comment: I think you should consider putting a div around all the divs of a given post. Something like <div class="Post1"> and then do a jquery selection based on that class first and then do a jquery find within that selection. 

Something like $( ".Post1" ).find(".show_2, .show_3") and then apply attributes.

Comment: $this is not a function but a variable; your code mixes the concept of class and id dangerously; and your fiddle has nothing to do with the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your markup:

```
<?php  if (is_page)()({
foreach ($posts as post): 
setup_postdata($post);//setup variables inside the loop  
?>
<div class="tab-container">
  <div class="container_left">
      <div data-content="1" class="show_1"><img></div>
      <div data-content="2" class="show_2 show_hidden"><img></div>
      <div data-content="3" class="show_3 show_hidden"><img></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container_right">
      <div class="inner_right">
          <div data-tab="1" class="button_1"></div>
          <div data-tab="2" class="button_2"></div>
          <div data-tab="3" class="button_3"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

And in your jQuery:

```
$(function () { 
    $('[data-tab]').on('click', function () {
        var $tab = $(this);
        var id = $tab.attr('data-tab');
        var $container = $tab.closest('.tab-container');
        var $contents = $container.find('[data-content]');

        $contents.addClass('show_hidden')
            .filter('[data-content="' + id + '"]')
                .removeClass('show_hidden');
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kem91mo6/1/).

Comment: Thank you, very elegant. Also sent me off learning something new "data specific tags". So a double tank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.index()`

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/PBbmf/14/)

```
$('.inner_right div').on('click', function () {
    position = $(this).index() + 1;
    $(".container_left > div").hide();
    $(".container_left > div:nth-child(" + position + ")").toggle();
})
```